# In golf, is there a rotational mechanical advantage of using a thicker grip?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics

I was asked to migrate this question to the physics exchange.

Ok, so many professionals are now using the new SuperStroke golf grips. I am basically thinking about the concept of a bigger grip, but for all golf clubs. For the irons, not necessarily as big as a SuperStroke grip, but bigger than the standard.

So first I'm reminded of my old physics classes. If you look at the gears of a clock, or any kind of mechanical gear action where a pipe/shaft is attached to a large gear, and the other end of the pipe/shaft is attached to a smaller gear, one inch of turn circumference on the larger gear effects the smaller gear based on how big the larger gear is. If the gear is huge, one inch of turn circumference will move the smaller gear less than if the larger gear happened to be very tiny.

So in putting or hitting, if the grip has a larger circumference, would that create more room for error in the rotation of the hands, thereby more room for error in the rotation of the club head? In other words, by having a larger grip, would there be any kind of mechanical advantage in terms of club head rotation relative to hand rotation?

If I have a tendency to rotate my hands within a range of +/- 1 inch of circumference, would the club head rotate within a smaller range if the grip was bigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a wide circumference grip, a small displacement on the surface will result in a smaller rotation of the club. This can be expressed mathematically: for a displacement $d$ along the surface of a cylinder with radius $r$, the angle $\theta$ is given by

$$\theta = \frac{d}{r}$$

As you can see, the larger $r$, the smaller $\theta$ for the same value of $d$.

On the other hand, if your hands rotate through a given *angle*, then giving yourself a bigger grip makes it easier to rotate the club (you have bigger torque). Imagine trying to spin a wheel: it's easier to do so by gripping the wheel near the outside than near the axle.

So if you believe your hands move by a constant *distance*, then the wide grip will help; if you think they move by a constant *angle*, then you will more easily transmit that change in angle to the club.

What happens in the actual club is more a question of biomechanics than physics - but those are the underlying physical principles.

Comment: I would think rotational resistance in such a small club from the hands would be negligible, so the torque would be negligible, meaning less club rotation from the bigger grip??? Thanks

Comment: I expect you are right but we don't have the parameters well enough defined to calculate it.